# Django filter dropdown Dynamially to remove previously selected value

Tags: jquery, django, filter, dropdown

I have 4 dropdown menu and all of them are populated through a django model. So, let's say values are primary key and when I select any value in the first dropdown, it should not be available in the remaining dropdown menu.

I already searched and tried the accepted jquery answer from
[Similarly asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518078/cascading-dropdown-remove-previous-selected) but it doesn't work at all.

Here is my sample code:

```
#views.py

from .models import myModel

def myFunction(request):
    data = myModel.objects.all()
    return render(request,'myPage.html',{'myData':data})

#myPage.html
<table>
<div id="select-group">
<tr>
   <td>
    <select name="dd1" id="dd1">
    {% for data in myData %}
       <option value={{data.id}}>{{data.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>
    <select name="dd2" id="dd2">
    {% for data in myData %}
       <option value={{data.id}}>{{data.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
... and rest
</div>
</table>
```

```
#jQuery
$('#select-group select').change(function(){
    var values = [];
    $('#select-group select').each(function(){
        if(this.value.length > 0)
            values.push(this.value);
    });

   $('#select-group select optgroup').each(function(){
        $(this).after('<option>'+          $(this).attr('label')+'</option>').remove();
    });

    $('#select-group select option').each(function(){   
        if($.inArray(this.value, values) > -1 &&
           !this.selected)                
        $(this).after('<optgroup label="'+this.value+'"></optgroup>').remove();
    });

});​
```

What am I missing ? is something wrong in the jQuery ?

Comment: Try these two questions: - [Disabling the submit botton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151402/how-to-select-unique-values-from-multiple-dropdown-lists-using-javascript/30152005) - [Another version using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601682/unique-select-option-values)

Comment: @cpy24 Another version helped thanks. Though i would say the answer from @Kender needed `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jQuery works perfectly...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var selectedValues = [];
  $('select').each(function() {
    var thisValue = this.value;
    if(thisValue !== '')
      selectedValues.push(thisValue);
  }).each(function() {
    $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').each(function() {
      if( $.inArray( this.value, selectedValues ) === -1 ) {
        $(this).removeAttr('hidden');
      } else {
        if(this.value !== '')
          $(this).attr('hidden', 'hidden');
      }
    });
  });
});
});
```